# What should I declare my object with when the class has an interface and a abstract superclass?

Tags: java

For instance I have

```
class Louie extends Chinese

abstract class Chinese implements Human

interface Human
```

Should I declare Louie objecta as Human, Chinese or just Louie?

One thing I also noticed is that the scopes for the object variables are not the same. For instance if I had a name variable in Chinese and a name variable in Louie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable of a super type can hold references of sub type.

This means:

```
Human h = new Louie();
Chinese c = new Louie();
Louie lui = new Louie();
```

Are all valid. But:

1. `h` can only access methods/fields declared in `Human` interface.
2. `c` can access methods/fields in `Human` interface as well as `Chinese` class.
3. `lui` can access methods/fields in `Human` interface, `Chinese` class and `Louie` class.

Now, to keep things simple, create only that kind of reference which has no extra access unless required.

For example: You are interested in `Human` interfaces methods only, then create a variable of type `Human`.

Answer (score 1):

it depend on what you want to do with the item.

if the interface has a method `IA()`, and the abstract superclass has method `B()`, and Louie class has implementation of both and method `C()` then:

in case that you only need to use the method `IA()` i would do:

```
Human h = new Louie();
```

in case you need to use `B()` i would do:

```
Chinese c = new Louie();
```

and if i need `C()` also i would do:

```
Louie l = new Louie();
```

the reason behind it is that it would be clear to everyone what i need from this instance. also, in method when i get `Louie` class, it depend again in what context i get it. if i get `Louie` as a method that deals or need to deal with all `Human` i would sign as:

```
public void DealWithHuman(Human h)
{
}
```

and so on. **It all depend on the context**

Answer (score 0):

Louie object can be declared as Human, Chinese or just Louie. Will be your choice and depends on requirement.
This is what comes form `polymorphism`.

So Louie object is can take any form Human, Chinese or Louie but Scope of that object will be restricted by the type to which you map it to.

Answer (score 0):

`Should I declare Louie objecta as Human, Chinese or just Louie?`
Simple answer is **yes**.

But note that

1.If you declare `Louie objecta as Human` you are allowed to use `Human` behaviour only.

2.If you declare `Louie objecta as Chinese` you are allowed to use both `Chinese` and `Human` behaviors only.

3.If you declare `Louie objecta as Louie` you are allowed to use all `Chinese` ,`Human` and `Louie` behaviors.

So it is completely depends on your requirement.